# Why dummy variables rather than one "factor" variable in modelling?

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I was speaking to a statistician recently who suggested that using dummy variables rather than one variable with several levels reduced the constraints on models, particular reducing the assumption of linearity. I didn't understand the explanation and was wondering if someone could make it clear?

Comment: Is the variable ordinal or nominal? If it's nominal, I don't understand his comment either, but if it's ordinal, I sort of vaguely see something.

Comment: I believe that some statistical packages will automatically convert ordinal variables (factor variables in R) to dummy variables in a linear regression, so you might not actually need to create dummy variables yourself. You might have essentially been following their advice without knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps he is saying that treating an ordinal variable as continuous (which is reasonably common) means more assumptions in the relationship to the response variable than if you treat it properly as a categorical factor (nominal or ordinal).

If you treat an ordinal variable as though it is continuous you are assuming that the differences between different adjacent levels of the scale are in some sense constant, as well as that this variable is linearly related to the response (assuming you have a linear model).

Comment: A good example I found online was if you code school type as: Elementary School (1), Middle School (2), High School (3), and College (4). By most measures, the difference between Elementary School and Middle School is not the same as the difference between High School and College.

Comment: Also, to illustrate the difference: if you code your school type variable in R as a numeric, it will be treated quite differently than if you code it as a factor (which I believe will create dummy variables under the hood). In the first case, it will be treated as continuous which makes no sense, though it may actually work.

Comment: And if you code it as an ordered factor you get an even more appropriate treatment that coded as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your research question. For the example of elementary school to high school. Let's say that you're trying to measure the Impact of educational level(niveau d'éducation) on the overall social behavior of a person. You will keep the ordinal/factor variable and eventually you will infer the overall relationship without knowing which level of education can predict social behavior better than others (for Instance, people with high school education level might exhibit better behavior than those who stopped at the elementary level).in this case,you need to use dummies.